# Optimizing polygon ordering

Tags: shapefile, software-recommendations, travelling-salesman

Does anyone know of any GIS tool that reorders polygons so that the path through all polygons is minimized, i.e. it solves the travelling salesman problem? Here's an example of just how poorly optimized a shapefile can be:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure from your brief description what you have and what you need. Reordering polygons in a shapefile is **technically and logically impossible**, their order is set by the FID which can't be manually changed, features will reorder but you have absolutely no control over how this happens.

Comment: @MichaelStimson If you *write* the features to a *new* shapefile, you can control the order, though you'd need to use something like a cursor to get the needed granularity.  I actually optimize my file geodatabase and PostgreSQL table feature order for optimal draw performance all the time (I don't use shapefiles anymore).

Comment: Isn't that what a spatial index is for @Vince? You're right, it is possible to write to a shapefile in a particular order **but** that order is so fragile I wouldn't depend on it, geodatabases on the other hand where the OID is kept for the lifetime of the row can be ordered as you say.

Comment: @MichaelPeters This isn't a traditional travelling salesman, though if you populated centroids and connected them in a network of near neighbors, that would bend the existing tools to work for you.

Comment: @MichaelStimson No, the spatial index is still impacted by spatial fragmentation, especially choosing thousands out of millions, so physical order can have a measureable impact on draw time. BTW: The FID in shapefiles isn't all that fragile; I just prefer a format that supports numeric NULLs and datetime values

Comment: How many nodes to visit? Up to a certain not very big number it is solved by permutations.

Comment: @FelixIP brute forcing this problem with a permutation approach is unworkable for my needs. Some sort of optimizing algorithm offers something more tractable (I'm leaning towards simulated annealing).

Comment: This https://github.com/MUSoC/Visualization-of-popular-algorithms-in-Python/tree/master/Travelling%20Salesman%20Problem approximation looks promising. I tried annealing, results are way too random. If you can compute distance matrix, the rest is pure python, no GIS needed. NetworkX makes life much easier.

Comment: Put it in postgis and cluster on the spatial index?

Comment: @Ian Turton I'm looking for a tool that is explicitly does this. AFAICT said tool does not exist, so it looks like I'm going to have to roll up my sleeves and develop it.

Comment: @Vince - googling around, this is actually the Hamiltonian path problem, the key difference is that the salesman returns to the start point, the Hamiltonian does not.

Comment: The issue is the topology.  Routing is done from a point to other points along a weighted network, not between polygons.

Comment: @Vince FWIW I'm not thinking in terms of polygons and centroids - I just care about the vertex where a polygon starts and ends.The polygons themselves are just along for the ride (I'd store them in a separate data structure - say a dynamic array for each node). Once a reasonably optimized path is found, the data structures get serialized and outputted. At least that's the plan...

Comment: Start point is an *unconventional* and somewhat arbitrary way to model a polygon. This is likely to introduce error into your modeling, and to make conventional tools unavailable.

Comment: @Vince The only way to know for sure is to try it and see what happens.